# SQL Counting # of times a member shows up with certain code values

Tags: sql

I am running a query that returns the location of a member and the product the member is enrolled in.  Each time a member makes a claim with their product, they get a revenue code associated to them.  Below is my query that I have now:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    e.State,
    f.Product,
    d.MemberID,
    b.RevenueCode
FROM
    Claims a
INNER JOIN
    dw.Revenue b
ON
    a.RevenueKey = b.RevenueKey
INNER JOIN 
    dw.Member d
ON
    a.MemberKey = d.MemberKey
INNER JOIN  
    dw.Product f
ON
    a.ProductKey = f.ProductKey
INNER JOIN
    dw.State
ON
    a.StateKey = f.StateKey
WHERE
    b.RevenueCode IN ('0134', '0135')
```

It returns a set like the following:

```
State         Product            MemberID              RevenueCode
MN            xxx                945-234-245           0134
MN            xxx                945-234-245           0135
SD            xxx                231-345-235           0134
```

When a MemberID has both 0134 and 0135 RevenueCodes associated with it, they are considered to be in a special category.  How would I modify my above query to count the number of times a MemberID has both RevenueCodes by State and by Product?

Comment: What do the desired results look like? just `MemberID, count`? or are you looking for `State, Product, count`?

Comment: Figured it out...Simply needed to Count the Distinct RevenueCodes and Group By State, Product, and MemberID

Comment: @Eric, I was just about to edit my answer to reflect the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...Simply needed to Count the Distinct RevenueCodes and Group By State, Product, and MemberID

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    e.State,
    f.Product,
    d.MemberID,
    b.RevenueCode.
    CASE WHEN EXISTS(
      SELECT NULL
      FROM Claims a1
      JOIN dw.Revenue b1 ON a1.RevenueKey = b1.RevenueKey
      JOIN dw.Member  d1 ON a1.MemberKey = d1.MemberKey
      JOIN dw.Product f1 ON a1.ProductKey = f1.ProductKey
      WHERE b1.RevenueCode IN('0134', '0135') AND 
        d1.MemberID = d.MemberID AND
        f1.ProductKey = f.ProductKey AND
        f1.StateKey = f.StateKey
    ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END As IsSpecialCategory
FROM
   ...
```

Comment: that won't work. The `CASE` statenent isn't closed off with `END` and also doesn't have an `ELSE`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    e.State
    ,f.Product
    ,d.MemberID
    ,b.RevenueCode
    ,(SELECT 1
    FROM Claims AS a1
    INNER JOIN dw.Revenue AS b1 ON a1.RevenueKey = b1.RevenueKey
    WHERE b1.RevenueCode IN ('0134', '0135')
        AND b.revenuekey = b1.revenuekey
        AND a.MemberKey = a1.Memberkey
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT b1.RevenueCode) = 2) AS SpecialCategory
FROM Claims a
INNER JOIN dw.Revenue b ON a.RevenueKey = b.RevenueKey
INNER JOIN dw.Member d ON a.MemberKey = d.MemberKey
INNER JOIN dw.Product f ON a.ProductKey = f.ProductKey
INNER JOIN dw.State ON a.StateKey = f.StateKey
WHERE b.RevenueCode IN ('0134', '0135')
```

Comment: This returns all NULLS for me.